# Tsung Load-Test XMPP with TLS

Tags: xmpp, load-testing, ejabberd, tsung

Does anyone have an xml tsung configuration file with TLS implementation?  I want to test TLS Secured connections on my XMPP server, but I can't get the script running with TLS enabled.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM "/Users/Downloads/tsung-1-5-0/tsung-1.0.dtd">
<tsung loglevel="notice" version="1.0">
  <clients>
   <client host="localhost" use_controller_vm="true" maxusers="600"/>
  </clients>

  <!-- Server side setup -->
 <servers>
  <server host="chat.example.com" port="5222" type="tcp"></server>
 </servers>

  <load>
   <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="10" unit="minute">
    <users interarrival="0.01" unit="second"></users>
   </arrivalphase>
  </load>

  <!-- JABBER parameters -->
  <!-- to synchronise users,  use a global acknoledgement -->
 <options>
  <option type="ts_jabber" name="global_number" value="1000"></option>
  <option type="ts_jabber" name="userid_max" value="10000"></option>
  <option type="ts_jabber" name="domain" value="chat.example.com"></option>
  <option type="ts_jabber" name="username" value="tsunguser"></option>
  <option type="ts_jabber" name="passwd" value="tsunguser"></option>
 </options>

<sessions>
   <session probability="50" name="jabber-example" type="ts_jabber">

    <request> <jabber type="starttls" ack="local" cacertfile="%%_cacert%%" certfile="%%_certfile%%" keyfile="%%_keyfile%%" /></request>
    <thinktime value="2"></thinktime>
    <transaction name="authenticate">
      <request> <jabber type="auth_get" ack="local"></jabber> </request>
      <request> <jabber type="auth_set_plain" ack="local"></jabber> </request>
    </transaction>

    <request> <jabber type="presence:initial" ack="no_ack"/> </request>
    <thinktime value="2  "></thinktime>

    <transaction name="roster">
      <request> <jabber type="iq:roster:get" ack="local"></jabber></request>
    </transaction>

    <thinktime value="30"></thinktime>

    <transaction name="online">
    <request> <jabber type="chat" ack="no_ack" size="16" destination="online"></jabber> </request>
    </transaction>

    <thinktime value="30"></thinktime>

    <transaction name="offline">
      <request> <jabber type="chat" ack="no_ack" size="56" destination="offline"></jabber> </request>
    </transaction>

    <thinktime value="30"></thinktime>

    <transaction name="close">
      <request> <jabber type="close" ack="no_ack"></jabber> </request>
    </transaction>

  </session>

  <session probability="20" name="jabber-digest" type="ts_jabber">

    <!-- regexp captures stream ID returned by server -->
    <request>
      <dyn_variable name="sid" re="&lt;stream:stream id=&quot;(.*)&quot; xmlns:stream"/>
      <jabber type="connect" ack="local"></jabber>
    </request>

    <thinktime value="2"></thinktime>

    <transaction name="auth_digest">
      <request> <jabber type="auth_get" ack="local"></jabber> </request>
      <request subst='true'> <jabber type="auth_set_digest" ack="local"></jabber> </request>
    </transaction>
    <thinktime value="30"></thinktime>

    <transaction name="close">
      <request> <jabber type="close" ack="no_ack"></jabber> </request>
    </transaction>
  </session>


 </sessions>
</tsung>
```

This is the Error Log when i execute the xml. When i remove the TLS Part everthing works.

```
594- fatal: {failed_validation,
                {element_seq_not_conform,{wait,session},{is,jabber}}}
Config Error, aborting ! {fatal,
                             {{failed_validation,
                                  {element_seq_not_conform,
                                      {wait,session},
                                      {is,jabber}}},
                              {file,"jabber.xml"},
                              {line,112},
                              {col,1}}}
```

Comment: show us what you have tried. Post your script and we can try to help.

Comment: this the script so far it works without TLS.

Comment: What happens when you try to use TLS? Any errors?

Comment: This question could be re-opened now that further information has been given.

Comment: So what's on line 112 of `jabber.xml`?

Comment: Line 112 ist the empty space between </session> and </sessions> at the bottom of the script. I removed the spaces but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

use the below transaction values for "connect" with TLS

```
<transaction name="connect">
  <request> <jabber type="connect" ack="local"/> </request>
  <request> <jabber type="starttls" ack="bidi_ack"/> </request>
  <request> <jabber type="connect" ack="local"/> </request>
</transaction>
```

Also, you have to add options value as like below,

```
<options>
 <option name="ssl_reuse_sessions" value="false"/>
 <option name="ssl_versions" value="'tlsv1.2'"/>
</options>
```

Please cross check with server team about the TLS version.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

`element_seq_not_conform` error is probably Tsung complaining about elements sequence. Try to validate the XML against `tsung-1.0.dtd` to get a hint.

I got similar error yesterday. After validating the XML, I got following error.

> The content of element type "tsung" must match
> "(information?,clients,servers,monitoring?,load,options?,sessions)".

All required child elements (`<clients>`, `<servers>`, `<load>`, and `<sessions>`) were there in `<tsung>` element.

```
<tsung>
  <clients>...</clients>
  <servers>...</servers>
  <monitoring>...</monitoring>
  <options>...</options>
  <load>...</load>
  <sessions>...</sessions>
</tsung>
```

It looked like Tsung wants the child elements in the correct order. So I moved `<load>` above `<options>`.

```
<tsung>
  <clients>...</clients>
  <servers>...</servers>
  <monitoring>...</monitoring>
  <load>...</load>
  <options>...</options>
  <sessions>...</sessions>
</tsung>
```

Tsung doesn't complain anymore about the XML. It runs.

Answer (score -1):

Did you succed to run it without TSL?

Comment: Yes run's fine without TLS!

Comment: Could you help us how to do load testing without TLS ? Could you share the configuration file and command to run it ?